# Variable "form" does not exist. Symfony 4

Tags: mongodb, forms, search, symfony4

I am new to Symfony 4 and I am following this tutorial "https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/forms.html" but it does not recognize my variable "form" and I don't know why (everything is up to date).

My Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Task;
use App\Form\Type\TaskType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;



class TaskController extends AbstractController
{
    public function new(Request $request)
    {
        // creates a task object and initializes some data for this example
        $task = new Task();
        $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
        $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

        /*$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('task', TextType::class)
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Create Task'])
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->getForm();*/

        $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);

        return $this->render('search/search.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

My TaskType.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('task', TextType::class)
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Task::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my Task.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

class Task
{
    protected $task;
    protected $dueDate;

    public function getTask()
    {
        return $this->task;
    }

    public function setTask($task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }

    public function getDueDate()
    {
        return $this->dueDate;
    }

    public function setDueDate(\DateTime $dueDate = null)
    {
        $this->dueDate = $dueDate;
    }
}
```

If you see any error from my part I am open..

I am calling my form here :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form(form) }}

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

In my "search.html.twig".

Comment: I add a routes in my config/routes.yaml :
"taskCheck:
  path: /search
  controller: App\Controller\TaskController::TaskController"

But nothing change..

Comment: I don't see any problem except the "Task" entity annotations. Is this real entity codes or you could removed some of the lines?

Comment: Yes I can, but I abandoned this solution.